# How to show pop up on clicking map overlay?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show a custom image with some data in it while clicking map overlay that i have added to google map in android.

Can any one guide me how can i create that custom image or thing to be displayed on google map with some data on it?

some body told me to go for custom view but i have no idea about them.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do. You can register an onclicklistener to a point on you map overlay and then display in a toast message. You can add images to the toast message as well. 
I could give some examples if you specify your problem a little bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/EvenNooerYawk/) demonstrates adding popup panels (ones that persist, unlike a `Toast`) over top of a map.

Answer (score 2):

To create a custom toast message that shows an image and some text use this java code.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);

text.setText(content);
ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageBitmap(bmImg);


Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

and this layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:background="#DAAA"
          >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_width="40dp"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           />
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes it was helpful but instead of toast can i show something to stay on screen. toast appears then disappear. images come in toast but not toast in shape of image.

Comment: add another view(it my be text or image view). when u tap that u can setVisibility() for that. for more: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Visibility1.html

Comment: Just fixed the code to initialize image before you "setImageBitmap" it. Please confirm.