# Android: Create Info box when cluster icon in Map , is clicked

Tags: android, android-maps, android-dialog

In My Map project, I have placed cluster icons in the map. I just want to create info box when an icon is clicked. I have already change the icon image when cluster icon is clicked. In added with i want to display the details of the icon in infoBox.

I have write a code for changing icon in onTap() of Custom Overlay class, So i need the correct code in that place

Please provide me the right way to do that.....

Comment: Look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486864/how-to-display-popup-on-tapping-overlay-in-android

Comment: Is there any native info box for the cluster pin