# Creating a button after tapping on map

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to create a button after tapping on my google map exactly like this : 
[image]

How can I do that ? Please help guys .

This is the method showing the map :

```
public void showMap() {
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls();
    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
            latitude = 23.765764900000000000;
            longitude = 90.391317200000000000;
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    point = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (latitude*1E6),
            (int) (longitude*1E6));
    mapController.animateTo(point);
    mapController.setZoom(17);
    mapView.invalidate(); }
```

Comment: Its not a button. IT is popupwindow i think.. Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486864/how-to-display-popup-on-tapping-overlay-in-android

Comment: actually I want to get the location from tapped point on the map . So , the popup or whatever it is , will be used for confirming the point of the map & send the geolocation to the code . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
mapview.onTouchListener(this);
```

Then make sure your mapactivity implements the ontouchlistener. You'll be able to get the x and y position from the touch event.

You then use use mapview.getProjection() to convert your x and y to geocode coordinates.